# How do I remove or disable "Or link to existing content" in "insert link" dialogue?

Tags: links, editor

Don't ask why. Image below pretty much ask what I'm looking to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The why is actually interesting as you can just close it if it is UI related, but if it is performance related you block it in the GUI or block the ajax request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could hook into the `after_wp_tiny_mce` with some CSS to hide it, if the `wplink` editor plugin is loaded.

**Example:**

```
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', function( $settings )
{
    // Check for the 'wplink' editor plugin
    if(    isset( $settings['content']['plugins'] ) 
        && false !== strpos( $settings['content']['plugins'], 'wplink' ) 
    )
        echo '<style>
                  #link-selector > .howto, #link-selector > #search-panel { display:none; }
        </style>';
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in your functions.php file

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post.php',     'wpse22643_overwrite_wplinks' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'wpse22643_overwrite_wplinks' );

function wpse22643_overwrite_wplinks( $hook ) {

    // register is important, that other plugins will change or deactivate this
    wp_register_script(
        'overwrite-wplinks', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/overwrite-wplinks.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '',
        TRUE
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'overwrite-wplinks' );
}
```

Double check the path to the js file you want to include above (**/js/overwrite-wplinks.js**). Then place the following code in the above mentioned js file.

```
( function( $ ) {

   if ( typeof wpLink == 'undefined' )
       return;

   wpLink.setDefaultValues = function () { 

   $('#link-selector p:nth-child(2).howto').css('display','none');

  };

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: ps: there are other unrelated parts with `p.howto`, like the `#new-tag-post_tag-desc` paragraph in the post tag meta-box and the "Enter the destination URL" paragraph.

Comment: Ah.. @birgire thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my code above to target specific `p.howto` inside `#link-selector`. I also checked `#new-tag-post_tag-desc` for tag meta-box but did not notice its affecting/hiding `p.howto` there. @lee - The solution which Birgire's provide is more specific. So you can use that instead of mine. If you decide to use mine, please note the slight change I made in `$('#link-selector p:nth-child(2).howto').css('display','none');`

Answer (score 0):

I found this code some ones blog but it worked for me , Solved my problem

```
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', function( $settings )
{
    // Check for the 'wplink' editor plugin
    if(    isset( $settings['content']['plugins'] )
        && false !== strpos( $settings['content']['plugins'], 'wplink' )
    )
        echo '<style>
                  #link-selector > .howto, #link-selector > #search-panel { display:none; }
        </style>';
} );
```

Comment: add that above code in functions.php

Comment: Please file edits instead of comments. Also explain **why** it helps the OP to solve the problem.

Comment: This seems to be from my answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/212922/26350)